# Setting rownames = FALSE in DT::renderDataTable() fails to render table in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt, shinyapps

I am building an R Shiny app that renders a datatable. By default, it is rendering a datatable with row names column, being a index of numbers from 1 to the number of rows in the data table. I want to render the table without this column. Following documentation online, I set the 'rownames' argument of the datatable to FALSE. This results in no rows rendering at all. Here is the code I am using that produces this:

```
  output$suggested_apps_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(
        ui_category_param <- getSelectedCategoryFilter()
        getFilteredDataCompliment() 

        %>%

        select(c("APPL_ID","PROJECT_TITLE","FY",{{ ui_category_param }})) %>%
          mutate_at(vars({{ ui_category_param }}), funs(round(., 4))) 
          
      
      ,selection="single"
      ,options = list(order=list(4, "desc"))
      ,rownames = FALSE
      
    )
  })
```

Without the `rownames = FALSE` argument, the rows render normally. Any help here would be appreciated.

I tried using `rownames = FALSE` argument to remove the index column.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe include `sessionInfo()` so we can see what packages you have loaded and what versions of those packages are installed. What you have shared looks like it should be triggering a syntax error. You seem to be passing multiple expressions to the first prameter of `datatable()`. That shouldn't be allowed outside of a `{}` block.